# parseFloat del valor de un input retorna NaN en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tomando valores de los inputs de un formulario, para luego hacer una serie de operaciones matemáticas y llenar otros inputs a partir de esta. Ya toma el valor de forma correcta con este 
    codigo

```js
function calculateTotals(subtotdesc,descuento,impuesto,totaln,accion){
    var t_venta=document.getElementById("total_venta").value;
    var t_descuento=document.getElementById("total_descuento").value;
    var t_impuesto=document.getElementById("total_impuesto").value;
    var t_total= parseFloat(document.getElementById("total_comprobante").value);
    console.log(t_total);
    //returns NaN
    if(accion==1){
        document.getElementById("total_venta").value=(parseFloat(subtotdesc));
        document.getElementById("total_descuento").value=(parseFloat(descuento));
        document.getElementById("total_impuesto").value=(parseFloat(impuesto));
        document.getElementById("total_comprobante").value=(t_total)+(totaln);
    }else if(accion==2){
        document.getElementById("total_venta").value=(parseFloat(subtotdesc));
        document.getElementById("total_descuento").value=(parseFloat(descuento));
        document.getElementById("total_impuesto").value=(parseFloat(impuesto));
        document.getElementById("total_comprobante").value=(t_total)-(totaln);
    }
}
```

El problema es que al querer llenar la información en el input de total compronbante me lo concatena en lugar de sumar Es decir que lo toma como un string y no como Número. Por lo tanto como se puede ver en el código, le **hice un parseFloat**, pero **en lugar de funcionar correctamente me devuelve un NaN**

input en el cual debo llenar la sumatoria:

```
<input type="text" id ="total_comprobante" name="total_comprobante" placeholder="" class="wide-input  bold" disabled>
```

Comment: El NaN te da en donde en `console.log` o el las lineas del if `document.getElementById("total_comprobante").value=(t_total)+(totaln);` y `document.getElementById("total_comprobante").value=(t_total)-(totaln);`

Comment: Formula mejor tu pregunta por favor

Comment: En ambos, el script funciona de manera correcta para tomar los valores del input por su id, solo que al realizarle el parse me regresa un NaN.

Comment: Es necesario realizarle el parse, ya que de lo contrario lo toma como un string y me hace una simple concatenación. (En lugar de sumarme me pone un numero al lado del otro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posibilidad sería definir esos inputs como `type="number"` en vez de `type="text"`

```js
contenedorInputs = document.getElementById("contenedor_inputs");



['total_venta', 'total_descuento', 'total_impuesto', 'total_comprobante'].forEach(id => {
  let grupo = $('<div/>').addClass('grupo'),
    label = $('<label/>')
    .text(id.split('_').join(' '))
    .appendTo(grupo),
    campo = $('<input type="number"/>')
    .addClass('campo')
    .attr('id', id)
    .appendTo(grupo);

  grupo.appendTo($(contenedorInputs));
});

function reset() {

  $('.campo').each((index,campo)=>{
   campo.value = Number(parseFloat(7 + Math.random() *9, 10)).toFixed(2);
  }); 
}

reset();
```

```css
label,
.grupo,
#total {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
    clear: left;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px 0;
}

.campo,
#total_neto,
.campo_normalizado {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
}
label {
  width: 140px;
}
.contenedor {
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width:70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor" id="contenedor_inputs">
  <b> No acepto texto!</b>
</div>
```

Aunque eso no es infalible. Lo otro, que hice como prueba de concepto, es que al momento de calcular el total hagas una normalización , donde el valor que realmente cuenta es el que sale de reemplazar los NaN con cero.

```js
function normalizar() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.campo')].forEach(campo => {
    let id = campo.id,
      numerico = parseFloat(campo.value, 10) || 0;

    $(`#${id}_normalizado`).val(numerico || 0);
  });
}

function reset() {
  $('.campo').each((index, campo) => {
    campo.value = Number(
        (16 * (index + 1)) + parseInt(7 + Math.random() * 9, 10)
      )
      .toString(16)
      .split('').reverse().join('')
      .toUpperCase();
    $(`#${campo.id}_normalizado`).val('');
  });
}
document.querySelector('#normalizar').addEventListener('click', e => {
  normalizar();
  $('#normalizar').hide();
  $('#reset').show();
});
document.querySelector('#reset').addEventListener('click', e => {
  $('#normalizar').show();
  $('#reset').hide();
  reset({});
});



contenedorInputs = document.getElementById("contenedor_inputs");

['total_venta', 'total_descuento', 'total_impuesto', 'total_comprobante'].forEach(id => {
  let grupo = $('<div/>').addClass('grupo'),
    label = $('<label/>')
    .text(id.split('_').join(' '))
    .appendTo(grupo),
    campo = $('<input/>')
    .addClass('campo')
    .attr('id', id)
    .appendTo(grupo),
    campo_normalizado = $('<input/>')
    .addClass('campo_normalizado')
    .attr('id', `${id}_normalizado`)
    .appendTo(grupo);

  grupo.prependTo($(contenedorInputs));
});
reset();
```

```css
.grupo,
label {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px 0;
}
label {
  width: 140px;
}
.campo,
.campo_normalizado {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
}

.campo_normalizado {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.contenedor {
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.w60 {
  width: 53%;
}

.w40 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 38%;
}

#normalizar,
#reset {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #69A;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#reset {
  background: #393;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor w60" id="contenedor_inputs">

</div>

<div class="contenedor w40">
  <button id="normalizar">Normalizar</button>
  <button id="reset" style="display:none;">Empezar de nuevo</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Ayer finalmente dí con la solución, en lugar de hacerlo con ParseFloat, lo hice con el método Number y funciono. Probé con la tuya y también funcionó